# Append lists smartly?

Tags: list

How do I append two lists together, and delete duplicates?

For example:

```
(setq list1 ("a" "b" "c"))
(setq list2 ("b" "c" "d"))

(setq list3 (a b c))
(setq list4 (c d e))

;; use case
(append-list-to-list list1 list2) ; ("a" "b" "c" "d")
(append-list-to-list list3 list4) ; (a b c d e)
```

*UPDATE after the `cl-union` answer:* I need to preserve the order of the resulting list.

And when there is a nested list, how do I append and make element is unique in list.

For example:

```
(a (b c) d) or ((a b) c d) etc
add list (x y z) to list ((a b) c d) to become ((a b x y z) c d)
```

Then how to append a new list to upper nested list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant your first case to result in `'(a b c d)` but correct me if I'm wrong.

It seems like you're looking for the logical union, this is available as `cl-union` or if you want to use the [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) library you can use their provided `-union`.

`(cl-union '(a b c) '(b c d)) -> '(a b c d)`

Comment: Common Lisp `union` makes no guarantees about the order: "*The order of elements in the result do not have to reflect the ordering of list-1 or list-2 in any way.*" -- [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_unionc.htm). The OP does not specify the requirements clearly, but the examples seem to preserve order, and the word `append` is used, which strongly suggests order preservation. (And yes, presumably the `list1` + `list2` examples shows the wrong result.)

Comment: What if I have a nested list2 in list1, then how to do?

Comment: It depends on the behavior you're looking for. A union would keep the nested lists. Perhaps you want to do something like flattening first? If so, again [dash.el#flatten](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-flatten-l) can help.

Comment: There are more questions that need to be answered: what to do when the original lists contained duplicates? What equality function should be used to establish that two elements are equal. If elements are found to be equal, which one should be used?

Answer (score 8):

[`append`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/append.html) does what the first part of your question asks:

> `(append &rest SEQUENCES)`
>
> Concatenate all the arguments and make the result a list.
>   The result is a list whose elements are the elements of all the arguments.
>   Each argument may be a list, vector or string.
>   The last argument is not copied, just used as the tail of the new list.

[`delete-dups`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sets-And-Lists.html) does what the second part of your question asks:

> `(delete-dups LIST)`
>
> Destructively remove `equal` duplicates from LIST.
>   Store the result in LIST and return it.  LIST must be a proper list.
>   Of several `equal` occurrences of an element in LIST, the first
>   one is kept.

```
(setq temp1 '(a b c))
(setq temp2 '(c d e))

(append temp1 temp2)                ; => (a b c c d e)
(delete-dups (append temp1 temp2))  ; => (a b c d e)
```

There are also Common Lisp options in the [`cl-lib`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/) library, if you're interested.

I did not understand what you meant in your question update about nested lists.  Let me suggest you remove the nested lists from this question and post it as a separate question.